# How to configure Spring / Springboot to access the home page?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to build my first web app with Springboot (JPA, H2) and Thymeleaf.

My goal is to get / modify / delete data stored into a database (`entities/`) through controllers (`controllers/`).

However, the home route doesn't work.

Can you tell me and explain me what I did wrong? I forget to configure something?

Thanks for help!

**Error**

URL : `localhost:8082/`

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Mar 08 14:22:21 CET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

**IndexController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView getHome(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Folders**

```
projetname/
|__src/
   |__main/
      |__java/
          |__projectname/
          |    |__controllers/
          |    |  |__IndexController.java
          |    |__entities/
          |    |__repositories/
          |    |__App.java
          |__resources/
              |__static/
              |   |__css/
              |   |__js/    
              |__templates/
              |   |__index.html 
              |__data.sql
              |__application.properties
```

Comment: follow this, and you'll have a working service in a matter of minutes: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: `@RequestMapping` of `/` on both the controller and the method might be the problem. That'll map to `//`. You can remove the class-level one.

Comment: @Stultuske I already tried to follow this doc.

Comment: @Michael even if I remove `@RequestMapping("/")` I still have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf is included as dependencies of the project.

[this guide may help](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Comment: How can I missed that ... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When application started look at it's log and find mappings like

```
2019-03-08 17:52:24.864  INFO 9592 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public hello.Greeting hello.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String)
```

This means you can call URL with /greeting and it is mapped to correspondent controller

404 error means you call URL that is not mapped